Retailer refusing to refund the money for the package that UPS delivered to the wrong person
Earlier this summer, we ordered three Rimowa cardholders totaling about $1,000 as small gifts for my wedding party. However, UPS delivered them to the wrong recipient, as indicated by the proof of delivery, which shows a signature from someone named "Clark." We don’t know anyone by that name, and we live in an apartment building with a shared mailroom that lacks a concierge or anyone else authorized to accept packages.
Rimowa refused to issue a refund, claiming the package was delivered. We then disputed the charge with Amex, and they initially canceled it. But after about a month, Amex re-billed us because Rimowa provided the same proof of delivery (showing Clark’s name) to support their case. We contacted Amex again, and they canceled the charge a second time, only for it to be re-billed again a month later when Rimowa sent in the same proof of delivery yet again. Essentially, all the evidence shows is that UPS delivered the package to someone other than us.
This would almost be funny if it weren’t so frustrating. While we could keep going through the dispute cycle with Amex, is there a better approach here? Would it make sense to consider legal action against Rimowa?
For reference, we’re in California (USA).

IANAL, but I'd keep going through the cycle. My guess is that it's much easier for you to dispute the charge than for them to show the same proof of delivery. I would recommend when you dispute the charge letting AMEX know you've already been through this cycle twice, and that each time the evidence the other company has provided has been evidence that the package got delivered to someone else.

The AMEX thing will not work.  Your only hope is to take Rimowa to small claims court; or, shame them on social media.

The signature with another name doesn't really prove anything. For all they know, you might have deliberately signed with a false name, planning to lie and claim that you didn't receive the package, and thus get a refund while keeping the goods as well.

But who has the burden of proof here?
